# How to receive a signal

Tags: c, signals

I wanted to write a daemon on receiving signals that I could run in the background.

I am a little confused however on how could I receive a signal? Once I receive a signal, can I display that received signal?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

// Define the function to be called when ctrl-c (SIGINT) signal is sent to         process
void
signal_callback_handler(int signum)
{
   printf("Caught signal %d\n",signum);
   // Cleanup and close up stuff here

   // Terminate program
   exit(signum);
}

int main()
{
   // Register signal and signal handler
   signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);

   while(1)
   {
      printf("Program processing stuff here.\n");
      sleep(1);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I feel like this code would work but if I wanted to do it for all 31 available signals, would i have to register each signal using `signal(SIGNAL, handler)`?

Comment: Neither `printf()` or `exit()` can safely be called in a signal handler, btw. [List of signal-safe functions](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: yes, you need to register a handler(s) for all signals of interest. note that not all signals can be caught. SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught or masked.  So, do not bother registering them.